# Typing single quotes in InDesign

Tags: typography, adobe-indesign

Every time I type character `'` InDesign converts it to `›`; why? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Preferences → Dictionary, in the middle of the dialog box, you have drop-downs for "Double quotes" and "Single quotes." Make sure you have selected " and ' rather than << and <.